# How to convert a wav file into RGB image with melspectogram?

Tags: python, signal-processing, spectrogram, librosa

I am working on sound classification with wav files ranging from 1 second to 4 second.
i want to convert wav to 224x224x3 image that i can fee into Resnet for classification
*The conversion should be using melspectogram* 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) to produce mel spectrogram like this:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.util.example_audio_file()) # your file
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, n_mels=128, fmax=8000)
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max), fmax=8000)
plt.savefig('mel.png')
```

Mind though that these are false colours, RGB does not make sense here - nor any multi-channel. Use architecture that works with a single channel.

Comment: This includes axis markers/labels etc from the plot into the file, which is not great as input to a ML model. Instead should save just the raw spectrogram data. An example of that in, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719138/how-can-i-save-a-librosa-spectrogram-plot-as-a-specific-sized-image/57204349#57204349

Comment: I tried this, and I got AttributeError: module 'librosa' has no attribute 'display'. You need to explicitly import librosa.display now.

Comment: You also need to import numpy as np, because you're using it on line 6

Comment: Thanks @Octaviotastico! Edited.