# How can I save a Librosa spectrogram plot as a specific sized image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, librosa

So I'm wanting to feed spectrogram images to a convolutional neural network as an attempt to classify various sounds. I want each image to be exactly 384x128 pixels. However, when I actually save the image it is only 297x98. Here's my code:

```
def save_spectrogram(num):
  dpi = 128
  x_pixels = 384
  y_pixels = 128
  samples, sr = load_wave(num)
  stft = np.absolute(librosa.stft(samples))
  db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(stft, ref=np.max)
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_pixels//dpi, y_pixels//dpi), dpi=dpi, frameon=False)
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
  ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
  ax.set_frame_on(False)
  librosa.display.specshow(db, y_axis='linear')
  plt.savefig(TRAIN_IMG+str(num)+'.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=dpi)
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how I can fix this? I've also tried doing it without the subplot, but when I do that it still saves as the wrong size AND has white space/background.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have a dpi of 128, and not closer to 100?  Otherwise, I think this post has good answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714454/specifying-and-saving-a-figure-with-exact-size-in-pixels

Comment: Why don't you simply pickle `db` and use the raw data as input to your CNN? Using an image (especially with lossy JPEG compression) is unlikely to give you the desired results.

Comment: How did you use this image for CNN? I am working on same and stuck at getting saved image to the model.

Answer (score 30):

Plots are for humans to look at, and contains things like axis markers, labels etc that are not useful for machine learning. To feed a model with an 'image' of the spectrogram, one should output only the data. This data be stored in any format, but if you want to use a standard image format then should use PNG. Lossy compression such as JPEG introduces compression artifacts.

Here follows working example code to save spectrogram. Note that to get a fixed size image output, the code extracts a fixed-length window of the audio signal. Dividing an audio stream into such fixed-length analysis windows is standard practice.

#### Example code

```py
import librosa
import numpy
import skimage.io

def scale_minmax(X, min=0.0, max=1.0):
    X_std = (X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min())
    X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
    return X_scaled

def spectrogram_image(y, sr, out, hop_length, n_mels):
    # use log-melspectrogram
    mels = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, n_mels=n_mels,
                                            n_fft=hop_length*2, hop_length=hop_length)
    mels = numpy.log(mels + 1e-9) # add small number to avoid log(0)

    # min-max scale to fit inside 8-bit range
    img = scale_minmax(mels, 0, 255).astype(numpy.uint8)
    img = numpy.flip(img, axis=0) # put low frequencies at the bottom in image
    img = 255-img # invert. make black==more energy

    # save as PNG
    skimage.io.imsave(out, img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # settings
    hop_length = 512 # number of samples per time-step in spectrogram
    n_mels = 128 # number of bins in spectrogram. Height of image
    time_steps = 384 # number of time-steps. Width of image

    # load audio. Using example from librosa
    path = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
    y, sr = librosa.load(path, offset=1.0, duration=10.0, sr=22050)
    out = 'out.png'

    # extract a fixed length window
    start_sample = 0 # starting at beginning
    length_samples = time_steps*hop_length
    window = y[start_sample:start_sample+length_samples]
    
    # convert to PNG
    spectrogram_image(window, sr=sr, out=out, hop_length=hop_length, n_mels=n_mels)
    print('wrote file', out)
```

#### Output

[image: Spectrogram stored as PNG image]

Comment: AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'io'.    You need to import skimage.io directly: import skimage.io

Comment: I don't know… probably it's just an Imgur artifact but in my browser your image is 385 pixels wide.

Comment: Imgur might recompress the image, which can sometimes give off by one size errors. If anyone can reproduce that locally it would be a bug

Comment: Is it possible to reconstruct (or at least estimate) the original .wav given the .png image? Thanks!
@jonnor

Comment: @obar Yes, reconstruction is possible. Though the phase reconstruction tends to make it quite noisy. See https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio.html

Comment: how can in have a colorful image for? It is possible ?