# How to use flask to receive wav file and load it with librosa?

Tags: python, flask, librosa

I received a wav file from the front end and got a FileStorage object with request.files.get('file'). How can I load it in librosa?

```
audio = request.files.get('file')
data, sampling_rate = librosa.load(audio)
```

and the error below showed
`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage`

I tried to use read() function

```
audio = request.files.get('file').read()
```

but it still doesn't work
`ValueError: _getfinalpathname: embedded null character in path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

librosa uses soundfile and audioread to read audio, but expects a path to the audio file. If you want to read audio from file-like objects you can use soundfile as well. You can find the documentation for this [here](https://librosa.org/doc/main/ioformats.html#read-file-like-objects).

```py
import soundfile as sf
import io

# ...

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('file')
        if file:
            tmp = io.BytesIO(file.read())
            data, samplerate = sf.read(tmp)
            
            # ...

    return render_template('upload.html')
```